Disabling "Skipped breakpoint" popups in IntelliJ
How do I disable the following popup in IntelliJ 2024?

The content of the popup is:

Skipped breakpoint at [location] because it happened inside debugger evaluation

This hides some of the stack frames, which is very annoying. How can I disable it? The expected result is no popup when a breakpoint is skipped.

Unfortunately, there's currently no direct setting to disable the popup in IntelliJ IDEA.
While not ideal, here are some potential workarounds to solve this problem:

Go to File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> Notifications.
Experiment with different notification types (balloons, tool window, etc.) and positions.

Disable all debugger notifications (extreme measure). If the popup window is very annoying, you can disable all debugger notifications. However, this will also disable other potentially useful notifications.

Adjust Breakpoint Behavior. Consider changing the breakpoint conditions or actions to reduce the frequency of pop-ups. For example, you can use conditional breakpoints or specific actions when a breakpoint is reached.


